# Error Despliegue WCF windows server 2012

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

Estoy realizando un despliegue de unos servicios `WCF`, al consumir los servicios; en un servidor funciona correctamente, pero en otro servidor en el cual debe estar desplegado, me esta lanzando el siguiente error:

```
The type initializer for 'Compensar.CyA.Mapper.Entidades.Servicio.ClienteEmpresaExtend' threw an exception.
   at Compensar.CyA.Servicios.Implementacion.ClienteEmpresa.<>c__DisplayClass14.<CrearSucursal>b__13()
   at Compensar.CyA.Servicios.Implementacion.LanzadorOperaciones.Ejecutar[TEntity](headerMessage header, Func`1 action)
```

He revisado los dos servidores, para encontrar las diferencias de configuración pero aún no doy con el chiste.

He encontrado el detalle del error

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ImplicitLoadAssemblyForType(Type type, Assembly callingAssembly)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetTypeUsage(Type entityCLRType)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySetFromContainer(EntityContainer container, Type entityCLRType, String exceptionParameterName)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySetForType(Type entityCLRType, String exceptionParameterName)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet[TEntity]()
   at Intergrupo.Data.Repository.EntityFramework.DataRepository`1.get_ObjectSet()
   at Intergrupo.Data.Repository.EntityFramework.DataRepository`1.GetFirst(Func`2 filtro)
   at Compensar.CyA.Dominio.GestionarCliente.Consultar(TipoCliente tipoCliente, ICollection`1 opcionesConsulta, Int32 tipoIdentificacion, String numeroIdentificacion, Decimal idSucursal, Decimal idCentroCosto)
   at Compensar.CyA.Servicios.Implementacion.ClienteEmpresa.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Consultar>b__7()
   at Compensar.CyA.Servicios.Implementacion.LanzadorOperaciones.Ejecutar[TEntity](headerMessage header, Func`1 action)
```

Pero aún no entiendo porque en un servidor si funciona y en el otro no.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: no dice cual es la exception?

Comment: puedes determinar en que accion se genera el problema? puedes atrapar el exception que se genera y loguearlo en un archivo en el servidor, o sea en el si puedes determinar cual es el OperationContract que lanza el problema definir su codigo dentro de un try..catch y loguear el problema

Comment: Si puedes atrapar el exception con un `try..catch` loguea la propeidad `LoaderExceptions`  del exception para tener un detalle del problema

Comment: atrape con el `try..catch` la excepción de tipo `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, donde no encontraba unas dll, como son `System.Web.Mvc.dll`, `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` entre otras, agregue las dll funcionó pero aún sigo con la duda de porque en un servidor funciono y en otro servidor no

Comment: seguramente porque al publicar las dll que mencionas estaban en el \bin, intenta ponerle Copy Local = true para que al compilar o publicar se copien   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Las dll se encuentran en Copy Local = true, pero se encuentran en una libreria de clases donde el servicio tiene la referencia de tal librería, de igual forma al publicar los servicios no quedan en la carpeta \bin

Comment: Porque una libreria de clase hace uso de librerias relacionadas a Web ? eso no es correcto. Esas librerias deberian ser referenciadas desde un proyecto web no en un Class Library, que pasa si las quitas? Nota: realiza un backup de la solucion en un zip por las dudas

Comment: En una librería compartida tanto para servicios como para una aplicación web, donde se implementa los Data annotations en algunos DTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>En una librería compartida tanto para servicios como para una aplicación web, donde se implementa los Data annotations en algunos DTO**

Ahí esta el problema no deberias usar validaciones de presentación con objetos persistentes, estos conceptos debes estar separados.

Por un lado debes definir las entidades de `EF` que usaras en el contexto y cuando estas deben unirse en la `UI` creas otros objetos diferentes conocidos como `ViewModel` si usas `asp.net mvc` estas clases estarán en la carpeta `Model`.

Entonces usas [automapper](http://automapper.org/) para mapear desde el controller una entidad de EF con una entidad que usa la view.

En tu caso por ser `WCF` es lo mismo pero lo realizas en el ServiceContract, por un lado tendras entidades de `DTO` (las cuales seguro tendran atributos DataMember) y por otro las entidades de `EF`, no deberias mapear de forma persistente ninguna entidad que uses hasta la presentacion.
Para convertir de una capa a otra usas `automapper`.

De esta forma separas responsabilidades y evitas tener referencias a librerias que no debes agregar como es el caso de librerias Web en proyecto `Class Library`.